# Additional Attributes Appearing in Rails Request Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httprequest

I've been seeing some functionality in my rails app whereby the parameters I pass through to rails are being encapsulated somewhere between the request and params in the controller.

It hasn't mattered before but I recently had an issue around this and so decided to try and find out why it was happening. I haven't had any luck and am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

My client request payload looks like this:

```
{
    "id"=>"1",
    "email" => "peter.hamilton10@imperial.ac.uk",
    "first_name" => "Peter",
    "last_name" => "Hamilton",
    "year" => 3,
    "private_attr" => "something"
}
```

And in rails, the logs show this

```
Started PUT "/students/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-29 13:20:56 +0000
Processing by StudentsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1",
               "email" => "peter.hamilton10@imperial.ac.uk",
               "first_name" => "Peter",
               "last_name" => "Hamilton",
               "year" => 3,
               "private_attr" => "something",
               "student" => {
                   "email"=>"peter.hamilton10@imperial.ac.uk",
                   "first_name"=>"Peter",
                   "last_name" => "Hamilton",
                   "year"=>3
               }
              }
```

**Where is this `student` attribute coming from and how are it's fields generated?**

I know attributes which can't be mass assigned don't appear (illustrated above by `private_attr`) so I assume its extracting fields for the model for the current controller but otherwise I'm slightly at a loss...

**UPDATE: Model**

```
# Schema
# create_table "students" do |t|
#   t.string   "email"
#   t.string   "first_name"
#   t.string   "last_name"
#   t.integer   "year"
#   t.integer   "private_attr"
# end
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :year
end
```

(NOTE: I don't expect private_attr to come through, I just did it as a test and thought it might be useful)

The request isn't actually coming from a form, it's coming from an ajax request generated manually.

Comment: Could you provide your model code?

Comment: Perhaps in your view you are using `form_for :student` or `fields_for :student` and then using the form object as e.g. `f.text_field :email` (and for the other fields that are under `"student" =>`), but for the other (not under "student") you are using `text_field` without the form object?

Comment: the view code could be interesting too

Comment: @244an I've added the model code to the question above. I'm not actually using a form, it does this from a manually defined ajax request.

Comment: Can u post yor form view as well?

Comment: @PeterHamilton, can you show how the ajax request is being built?

Comment: I think the since the request ends with `students/1` and it seems to be an update(?) Rails is probably doing this as an favor for you (fixing the subhash with attributes for student). Normally you want attributes to be under the object's key in the "param-hash" when you use it in e.g. an update. But, this is only a guess. Maybe some parameter in the controller are causing this...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at wrapped parameters:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

I don't know if you're using Rails 4 or not but this is the latest version of what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

In controller add following code:

**wrap_parameters :model, include: Model.column_names + [:attr]**

Model - your model, :attr - additional attribute